# Google App Script logger.log not showing anything

Tags: java, html

I writing a simple google web app. this .gs basically open a html file that require user to input his name then click. after the user clicked it, the function checkGCR() should log the username in logger.log. but nothing show in logger.log. if run the function checkGCR(), the log does record "null" since nothing input in the input box. One thing I notice is eventhough the logger.log didn't show anything, but stackdriver log doesn't showing something going on there. Please check my code is that something wrong I did here because I follow online tutorial with exact same coding but logger.log just doesn't seem to work.

```
//This is code.gs

function checkGCR(myid){

  Logger.log(myid);




}

//This is html

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);


    function doStuff(){

    var myid=document.getElementById("mykidid").value;
    google.script.run.checkGCR(myid);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that eventhough it doesn't show up at Logger.log, but it does show up in Stackdriver log. So I just use that instead.